# Should I uninstall all globally installed Python packages and only install them locally in VENV environments?

Tags: python, pip, package

I just read it's possible to have conflicts between globally and locally installed Python packages and that it's better to install Python itself and packages only in local VENV environments to avoid those potential problems.

I know I installed Python globally and (by mistake) Jupyterlab globally as well, but when I check `pip list` globally I get a long list of packages I don't remember ever installing, such as:

`anyio, argon2, async-generator, ..., ipython, Jinja2` (I have pycharm but isn't is supposed to only install locally when you create a new project?), `numpy, pandas`, etc...
many others, perhaps 50 other names.

Should I erase everything that's installed globally and only install Python itself and project relevant packages in VENV environments?

And if so, how?

Comment: you're probably seeing packages that dependencies to jupyterlab, etc.

Comment: Ideally, there should be no conflict in global and virtual env. If there are other Python projects you work on, you might need the global libs. In case a particular lib is throwing an error out of conflict, remove that particular one from the global env

Comment: You should only install packages using a virtualenv. But what Teejay says is the likely cause. Some packages depend on other packages which can depend on other packages. So you might install more packages than you would expect..

Comment: @EdoAkse, is it better to also install python only locally and never globally? Would you get rid of python + packages globally and reinstall whatever I need per project VENV? If so, how would I go about uninstalling all the globally installed packages?

Comment: Depends on your storage. I *very rarely* use my global installation. But I do use it. If you make sure your projects each use their own virtualenv and you source it properly, there's no harm in having a global installation of python...

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into something similar and thought I would add an answer here for future browsers.

As with many things, the answer is it depends... It would be good practice to only use virtual environments; this helps to ensure a few things, including ensuring that different projects can run on different versions of packages without conflict, or you needing to update packages, potentially breaking older pieces of code.

On the other hand, if you maintain multiple applications using any given package, you will have to update each of these venvs individually (if you want to update), making it something of an earache, in which case you might decide to install the package globally to save yourself the pain.

As for the original question RE: deleting everything, again, no one but you can answer this. My advice would be to (if it's manageable), check each package and delete it if you don't see yourself using it often enough to justify it being global.